# adequate way to define interfaces in java

Tags: java, interface

It's completely clear to me about the power of interfaces, how can help and the ease to implement those interfaces. What i'm trying to accomplish is

1. i own application CC (to put a name on it)
2. CC will use different inventory systems provided by 3rd party developers
3. 3rd party developers must implement interfaces defined by me (CC owner) with getInventory, updateInventory, returnToInventory.

So, my question is, what is the correct way to do this? What i'm doing is.

1. as CC owner, i created a jar that inside contains the mentioned interface with the 3 methods
2. im distributing this jar so 3rd party developers add this jar to their projects, implement this interface on their clases and returns me a jar with the result.
3. im adding the jars provided by the 3rd party developers inside CC and using their classes with type = my defined interface.

Is this procedure correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is correct although you don't have a requirement to combine them all into a mega-jar. I would leave all the JARs as they are.  One for the APIs and one for each implementation.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, yes, as an example, having 3 inventory providers, will cause 4 jars, the one where i define the interface and the providers use, and then 3 other jars, which the providers gave me back with their implementations.

Comment: @alexis_ar I use maven to build my applications and this tends to mean you can have lots of JARs.  This is not always the best solution but re-packaging JAR provided by others leads to lots of work for you, potentially every time one of them updates a JAR.

Comment: Absolutely, will be separated in my case, since will be a small amount of jars. Thanks a lot for the help